# Eclipse throwing 'Editor does not contain a main type' error when running Java program

Tags: java, eclipse

So I am trying to learn Java, but for some reason when ever I try to run my program in Eclipse I get this:

[image: Eclipse Error Window]

As you can see, the program is *very* simple (the first program I am supposed to write), so I don't know what's going on!

I haven't been able to find the log in the `workspace/.metadata/.log` folder as specified on the eclipse wiki and nothing appears when I launch eclipse from the terminal.

If it matters at all I installed eclipse from the archive downloaded from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html because I was originally going for learning how to make Android apps (then I figured I ought to learn Java first. :D)

Anyways, does anyone know what is causing this error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just realized after much deliberation and reading that ***facepalm*** I had forgot the `public static void main() { }`!

Wow. Anyways, it's now working and I am marking this as answered.